# Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject

Tags: django

```
class ProductDetailSlugview(ObjectViewedMixin, DetailView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = "products/product_detail.html"
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context=super(ProductDetailSlugview, self).get_context_data(*args , **kwargs)
        cart_object, new_object = Cart.objects.new_or_get(self.request)
        context['cart']=cart_object
        return context
```

this is my view

> ValueError at /product/list/blackberry Cannot assign
>   "
>   at 0x7f0488733860>>": "ObjectViewed.user" must be a "User" instance.
>   Request Method:   GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/list/blackberry Django
>   Version:  2.1.3 Exception Type:   ValueError Exception Value:  Cannot
>   assign "
>   object at 0x7f0488733860>>": "ObjectViewed.user" must be a "User"
>   instance. Exception
>   Location: /home/wiwigi/Desktop/django-virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py
>   in **set**, line 210 Python
>   Executable:   /home/wiwigi/Desktop/django-virtual/bin/python3 Python
>   Version:  3.6.5 Python Path:   ['/home/wiwigi/Desktop/ecommerce_sample',
>   '/home/wiwigi/Desktop/ecommerce_sample',
>   '/home/wiwigi/Desktop/django-virtual/lib/python36.zip',
>   '/home/wiwigi/Desktop/django-virtual/lib/python3.6',
>   '/home/wiwigi/Desktop/django-virtual/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.6',
>   '/home/wiwigi/Desktop/django-virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
>   '/home/wiwigi/pycharm-2018.1.2/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
>   Server time:  mar, 26 Fév 2019 11:31:14 +0000

and my error code please help me

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning an `AnonymousUser` object to the attribute `user` of an  `ObjectViewed` instance. From the naming, my guess is that this happens in the `ObjectViewedMixin`.

For a more definite answer, you have to post the full stack trace and the relevant code.

Comment: Ya this happening because of `AnonymousUser` assignment to the attribute `user` of an `ObjectViewed` but in my case the attribute `user` may be a User object or it can be `blank` or `Null` then why i am getting same error. How to get rid from this error `AnonymousUser` or not able to view Detail page.

Comment: @RahulVerma I'd suggest you post a separate question with the full stack trace and the relevant code

Answer (score -1):

This is because of you are accessing this view with out login (So it shows `AnonymousUser`) so you need to add `LoginRequiredMixin` to your class as below to ensure that only logged in users can visit this view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ProductDetailSlugview(LoginRequiredMixin, ObjectViewedMixin, DetailView):
    # rest of the code
```